# How to implement a semaphore

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

So I've created a program, trying to display the dangers of using shared variables, so I have 3 classes the main called `DangersOfSharedVariables` and an `Incrementer` and `Decrementer` class.

So the idea is to have two threads running at once, both calling their respected methods, so the `Decrementer` class will call the `decrementShared()` method in the main and the `Incrementer` class will call the `incrementShared()` method in the main.

**Here's the main method:**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package dangersofsharedvariables;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 */
public class DangersOfSharedVariables {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    private static int sharedValue =0;
    private static int numberOfCycles = 2000000000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Incrementer in = new Incrementer(numberOfCycles);
        Decrementer de = new Decrementer(numberOfCycles);
        Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1);


        in.start();
        try {
            in.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        de.start();
        try {
            de.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        System.out.println(sharedValue);
    }

    public void decrementShared(){
        sharedValue -=10;
    }

    public void incrementShared(){
        sharedValue +=10;
    }

}
```

**Here's the Incrementer class**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package dangersofsharedvariables;

/**
 *
 * 
 */
public class Incrementer extends Thread {

    private int numberOfIncrements;

    public Incrementer(int numberOfIncrements) {
        this.numberOfIncrements = numberOfIncrements;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        DangersOfSharedVariables in = new   DangersOfSharedVariables();
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfIncrements; i++){
            in.incrementShared();
        }
    }
}
```

**Decrementer Class:**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package dangersofsharedvariables;

/**
 *
 * 
 */
public class Decrementer extends Thread {
    private int numberOfDecrements;
    public Decrementer(int numberOfDecrements){
        this.numberOfDecrements = numberOfDecrements;

    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        DangersOfSharedVariables d = new DangersOfSharedVariables();
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfDecrements; i++){
            d.decrementShared();
        }
    }
}
```

I was googling and a more secure way to do this would be with the use of a Sempaphore class. So I took it upon myself to play around with a semaphore template I found, but am unsure as to how i'd implement it.

**Semaphore Class:**

```
package dangersofsharedvariables;

public class Semaphore {

    // *************************************************************
    // Class properties.
    // Allow for both counting or mutex semaphores.
    private int count;

    // *************************************************************
    // Constructor
    public Semaphore(int n) {
        count = n;
    }

    // *************************************************************
    // Public class methods.
    // Only the standard up and down operators are allowed.
    public synchronized void down() {

        while (count == 0) {

            try {
                wait(); // Blocking call.
            } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        count--;
    }

    public synchronized void up() {
        count++;
        notify();
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you want to write your own semaphore? There's already a `Semaphore` class in Java.

Comment: @Kayaman yeah was wondering how i'd use the semaphore I've implemented

Comment: @user3667111 please see my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your query, following is a brief description about semephore data structures. Semaphores are useful in solving a variety of synchronised problems. The concept has been introduced by Dijkstra(1968) where he introduced the idea of semaphores as part of the operating system in order to synchronise processes with each other and with hardware.

The structure of a typical semaphore involves 4 stages:

1. Non-critical region
2. Entry protocol
3. Critical region
4. Exit protocol

The non-critical region is any code which can be carried out concurrently by 2-n threads.

The entry protocol is the code which must be executed by a process prior to entering a critical region. It is designed to prevent the process from entering the critical region if another process is already using shared resources.

The critical region is the section of code in which a shared resource is being accessed.

The exit protocol is the code that the process must execute immediately on completion of its critical region.

Semaphores can be put to different uses:

1. for mutual exclusive access to a single shared resource, in which case the semaphore is called a **binary semaphore**
2. to protect access to multiple instances of a resource (a **counting semaphore**)
3. to synchronise two processes (a **blocking semaphore**)

The versatility of the semaphore mechanism is achieved through correct initialisation.

For demonstration purposes please consult example below which showcases the most simple binary semaphore implementation:

**Semaphore:**

```
package BinarySemaphore;

public class Semaphore{
    private static Semaphore semaphore;
    private static int resource = 1;

    private Semaphore(){}

    public synchronized void increment(){
        while(isAvailable()){
            try {
                this.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        resource += 1;

        report();

        this.notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized void decrement(){
        while(!isAvailable()){
            try {
                this.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        resource -= 1;

        report();

        this.notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized final static boolean isAvailable(){
        return resource == 1 ? true : false;
    }

    public synchronized final static void report(){
        System.out.println("Resource value: " + resource);
    }

    public final static Semaphore getInstance(){
        if(semaphore == null){
            semaphore = new Semaphore();
        }
        return semaphore;
    }
}
```

**Incrementer:**

```
package semaphore;

import BinarySemaphore.Semaphore;

public class Incrementer implements Runnable{
    private static Semaphore semaphore = null;

public Incrementer(Semaphore s){
    semaphore = s;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        System.out.println("Incrementing...");
        semaphore.increment();
    }
}
```

}

**Decrementer:**

```
package semaphore;

import BinarySemaphore.Semaphore;

public class Decrementer implements Runnable{
    private static Semaphore semaphore = null;

    public Decrementer(Semaphore s) {
        semaphore = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            System.out.println("Decrementing...");
            semaphore.decrement();
        }
    }
}
```

**Main:**

```
package semaphore;

import BinarySemaphore.Semaphore;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Thread iIncrement = new Thread(new Incrementer(Semaphore.getInstance()));
        Thread iDecrement = new Thread(new Decrementer(Semaphore.getInstance()));

        iIncrement.start();
        iDecrement.start();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Decrementing...
Incrementing...
Resource value: 0
Decrementing...
Resource value: 1
Incrementing...
Resource value: 0
Decrementing...
Resource value: 1
Incrementing...
Resource value: 0
Decrementing...
Resource value: 1
Incrementing...
Resource value: 0
Decrementing...
Resource value: 1
Incrementing...
Resource value: 0
Decrementing...
Resource value: 1
Incrementing...
Resource value: 0
Decrementing...
Resource value: 1
Incrementing...
Resource value: 0
Decrementing...
Resource value: 1
Incrementing...
Resource value: 0
Decrementing...
Resource value: 1
Incrementing...
Resource value: 0
Decrementing...
Resource value: 1
Incrementing...
Resource value: 0
Resource value: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The name for what you want is "mutex" which is short for "Mutual Exclusion".  A mutex is a block of code that can only be executed by one thread at a time.

The Java language statement `synchronized (foo) { ... }` implements mutual exclusion.  `foo` is an expression that yields up some object (sometimes called the *lock object*), and `...` are the statements to be protected.  The Java language guarantees that no two threads will be allowed to `synchronize` the same lock object at the same time.

---

`Semaphore` can be used to provide mutual exclusion, but it is more cumbersome, and it's antiquated.

`Semaphore` was invented before computers had hardware primitives for thread synchronization.  It was supposed to be the "primitive" operation upon which other synchronization constructs (e.g., mutexes) could be built.

Today, the Java implementation of `Semaphore` actually is built on top of the same hardware primitives as the `synchronized` statement.